# Running Installed Binaries from PHP Script (as apache)

Tags: php, apache, pygments

I'm trying to write a PHP script to run a fairly simple shell command.  The command is Pygmentize, which is a binary I have installed and is located in /usr/local/bin/pygmentize-1.4.  This works fine while in the command line of my web server (directory in apache server), but when I tried to include the statement in a PHP script it fails.

```
$command = "pygmentize -f html $extra_opts -l $language $temp_name";
$output = array();
$retval = -1;

exec( $command, $output, $retval );
echo $retval;
```

The command returns the value 127, which seems to mean that the script cannot find the binary, and I think I installed to the wrong location.  I installed it to a directory located in the same directory as the PHP script, but I'm not sure where to go from there.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I guess to summarize, how/where can I install Pygments such that it is accessible to my script?

Comment: use a full path, e.g. `"/path/to/pygmentize ..."`. Remember that exec() within Apache will have a different shell environment (including $PATH) than your standard login shells will.

Comment: try running it as `__DIR__."/pygmentize -f html $extra_opts -l $language $temp_name"`

Comment: you may also have to call putenv to get any of the environment variables that may be needed by the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use full path, because php runs under another user and `./` is not the apache directory when this user executes the script:

```
$command = "/usr/local/bin/pygmentize-1.4-f html $extra_opts -l $language $temp_name";
```